# Problema al cargar array de objetos desde el local storage

Tags: javascript, array, json, local-storage

Hola estoy haciendo una pagina de compras, imprime un listado de productos y luego con el boton de comprar, sumar o restar vas alterando el array de "carrito", obviamente para evitar productos duplicados en el carrito le puse un filter, el cual cumple su proposito pero cuando quiero cargar los productos desde el local storage con json el filter no funciona es como si lo ignorara y metiera los productos duplicados cargados desde el local storage de todas formas, la verdad no tengo idea que puede ser les dejo el codigo javascript
pd: que conste que use varios metodos para filtrar duplicados y contodos hace lo mismo

```
    let carrito = []

const DOMProductos = document.getElementById('wrapper')
const DOMcarrito = document.getElementById('cartList')
const DOMtotal = document.getElementById('total')
const DOMbotonVaciar = document.getElementById('boton-vaciar')

productos.forEach(producto => {
    //imprimo listado de productos
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.classList.add('card', 'col-4', 'col-sm-4', 'col-lg-3')
    card.innerHTML = `
        <img class="card-img-top" src=${producto.img}/>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3>${producto.nombre}</h3>
            <p>${producto.precio}$</p>
        </div>
    `
    DOMProductos.append(card)

    const boton = document.createElement('button')
    boton.classList.add('btn', 'btn-dark', 'btn-lg')
    boton.setAttribute('id', producto.id)
    boton.textContent = "Add to cart"
    card.appendChild(boton)
    boton.addEventListener('click', agregarProducto)
})
function agregarProducto(e) {
    //evento para agregar productos al carrito
    let productoEncontrado = productos.find((p) => p.id == e.target.id)
    carrito.push(productoEncontrado)

    renderizarCarrito()

}
 //esta funcion renderiza el carrito en el html
function renderizarCarrito() {
    
    DOMcarrito.textContent = ''


    //hago un filter para obtener elementos unicos del carrito y los paso a un array sin duplicados
    let carritoSinDup = carrito.filter((item, index) => {
        return carrito.indexOf(item) == index;
    })

    carritoSinDup.forEach((p) => {
        
        const productoCarrito = document.createElement('li')
        productoCarrito.classList.add('row', 'mt-3')
        //uso un reduce para contar la cantidad de veces que se repite 
        el producto 
        const cantidad = carrito.reduce((acc, item) => {
            if (item.id == p.id)
                return acc += 1
            else
                return acc
        }, 0)

        // imprime los productos del carrito en el html
        let { img, nombre, precio } = p
        productoCarrito.innerHTML = `
        <img class="w-25" src=${img}/>
        <p>${nombre} ${precio}$</p>  
        <p>Cantidad: ${cantidad}</p>
        `


        //agrega un boton para disminuir la cantidad de un producto
        const btnRestar = document.createElement('button')
        btnRestar.textContent = "-"
        btnRestar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-primary', 'w-25', 'btn-lg')
        btnRestar.setAttribute('id', p.id)
        productoCarrito.appendChild(btnRestar)
        btnRestar.addEventListener('click', restar)
        //agrega un boton para auemntar la cantidad de un producto 
        const btnSumar = document.createElement('button')
        btnSumar.textContent = "+"
        btnSumar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-danger', 'w-25', 'btn-lg')
        btnSumar.setAttribute('id', p.id)
        productoCarrito.appendChild(btnSumar)
        btnSumar.addEventListener('click', sumar)

        DOMcarrito.append(productoCarrito)
    })
    //calculo el total y lo imprimo al final del carrito
    DOMtotal.textContent = calcularTotal()
    guardarCarritoLocalStorage()
}

function restar(e) {
    let productoEncontrado = carrito.find((p) => p.id == e.target.id)
    let indice = carrito.indexOf(productoEncontrado)
    carrito.splice(indice, 1)
    renderizarCarrito()


}
function sumar(e) {
    let productoEncontrado = carrito.find((p) => p.id == e.target.id)
    carrito.push(productoEncontrado)
    renderizarCarrito()

}

function calcularTotal() {

    return carrito.reduce((acc, itemId) => acc + itemId.precio, 0)
}
function vaciarCarrito() {

    carrito = []
    renderizarCarrito()
    localStorage.clear()
}

function guardarCarritoLocalStorage() {

    localStorage.setItem('carrito', JSON.stringify(carrito))
}
function cargarCarritoLocalStorage() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('carrito')) {
        carrito = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('carrito'))
    }
}
cargarCarritoLocalStorage()
renderizarCarrito()
DOMbotonVaciar.addEventListener('click', vaciarCarrito)
```

Comment: Ya que tu código es largo, ¿podrías darnos mejores indicaciones acerca de dónde haces lo que nos comentas? Por ejemplo, en "le puse un filter" podrías indicarnos en las funciones en las que lo haces, también es interesante saber de qué función hablas cuando dices que "metiera los productos duplicados". Además, como buena práctica, te recomiendo el uso de comentarios en el código. Dado que no tenemos una vista global del funcionamiento de tu página (no tenemos ni HTML ni nada más) nos vendrían bien más indicaciones.

Comment: ahi agregue unos comentarios la parte del filter esta en la funcion renderizar carrito si quieres entender el funcionamiento interno de la misma te dejo esta pagina que lo explica https://matiashernandez.dev/blog/post/4-formas-de-eliminar-elementos-duplicados-en-un-arreglo-con-javascript

Comment: No necesito una página que me explique lo que hace el código, puedo entenderlo al leerlo. Quiero ahorrarme tiempo buscando aquello que dices que funciona mal. En cuando tenga un hueco, a partir del lunes, le echo un vistazo. Espero que otra persona pueda ayudarte mientras tanto.

Comment: Dale oscar cualquier ayuda me viene bien gracias

Comment: Gracias a todos por las recomendaciones la verdad es mi primera vez preguntando algo aca